# Windows Explorer Not Reading ID3 Meta Tags for Custom File Type

Tags: windows-8.1, meta-tags, windows-explorer, id3, shell-extensions

I created a custom binary file type with its own extension (**.atef**).
To provide some meta data about the file, I decided to implements the ID3 meta tags standard.

I hoped that **Windows Explorer** in Windows 8 would automatically detect the existence of the standard ID3 meta tags and automatically fill the appropriate columns with the right data. In this case I make use of the "**Title**" and "**Album Artist**" properties.

This is unfortunately not the case.

If I rename any of my custom .ATEF file to .MP3, the meta information are read and shown properly as I expected. I added the settings to the custom extension for the properties detail handler and info tip etc. It renders the right properties, but still without the actual meta data from the file itself.

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.atef

InfoTip     prop:System.Title;System.Music.AlbumArtist
FullDetails     prop:System.ItemType;System.Size;System.Title;
                    System.Music.AlbumArtist;System.ItemTypeText
TileInfo        prop:System.ItemTypeText;System.Size
```

Here is the link to an image that illustrates the issue
http://screencast.com/t/jpaBKAdlzc

**How do I tell Windows/Windows Explorer to read the ID3 meta tags from my files with my custom extension .ATEF, just as it already does with files that have the known .MP3 file extension?**

[image: Illustration of the Problem]

Answer (score 2):

Try to add the following registry value:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\PropertySystem\PropertyHandlers\.atef]
@="{C120DE80-FDE4-49f5-A713-E902EF062B8A}"
```